# trying to encrypt with bouncycastle throw error

Tags: java, aes, bouncycastle

I am trying to encrypt using bouncycastle jar here my code:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception
{
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(
            new AESEngine()));
    CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    aes.init(true, ivAndKey);
    return cipherData(aes, plain);
}
```

Here my main:

```
    String msg="hello";
    String key="123";

    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] keyB = new byte[16];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(keyB);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyB, "AES");

    byte[] enc=encrypt(msg.getBytes(),key.getBytes(),keyB);

    System.out.println(new String(enc));
```

but I/m getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine.generateWorkingKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at Aes.encrypt(Aes.java:122)
    at Aes.main(Aes.java:47)
```

Comment: The exception message tells you exactly what the problem is. Your key length is not an accepted number of bits.

Comment: 16 bytes is 128 bits @T_Bacon

Comment: Sure, but `key.getBytes()` is not returning 128 bits, is it?

Comment: Just as a quick test, run `System.out.println(key.getBytes().length)` and you will see that it is in fact 3 bytes and therefore only 24 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing what you think are into the `encrypt()` method:

```
String key="123";
…
byte[] enc=encrypt(msg.getBytes(),key.getBytes(),keyB);
```

You're passing the encoded string content, NOT the key array you create a few lines in.

Comment: This kind of bug would be easy to find in a debugger.